# How to properly encapsulate an asyncio Process

Tags: python, oop, python-asyncio

I have a program executed in a subprocess. This program runs forever, reads a line from its `stdin`, processes it, and outputs a result on `stdout`. I have encapsulated it as follows:

```py
class BrainProcess:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        # starting the program in a subprocess
        self._process = asyncio.run(self.create_process(filepath))

        # check if the program could not be executed
        if self._process.returncode is not None:
            raise BrainException(f"Could not start process {filepath}")

    @staticmethod
    async def create_process(filepath):
        process = await sp.create_subprocess_exec(
            filepath, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

        return process

    # destructor function
    def __del__(self):
        self._process.kill() # kill the program, since it never stops
        # waiting for the program to terminate
        # self._process.wait() is asynchronous so I use async.run() to execute it
        asyncio.run(self._process.wait())

    async def _send(self, msg):
        b = bytes(msg + '\n', "utf-8")

        self._process.stdin.write(b)
        await self._process.stdin.drain()

    async def _readline(self):
        return await self._process.stdout.readline()

    def send_start_cmd(self, size):
        asyncio.run(self._send(f"START {size}"))

        line = asyncio.run(self._readline())
        print(line)
        return line
```

From my understanding [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) is used to run asynchronous code in a synchronous context. That is why I use it at the following lines:

```py
# in __init__
self._process = asyncio.run(self.create_process(filepath))

# in send_start_cmd
asyncio.run(self._send(f"START {size}"))
# ...
line = asyncio.run(self._readline())

# in __del__
asyncio.run(self._process.wait())
```

The first line seems to work properly (the process is created correctly), but the other throw exceptions that look like `got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`.

Code:

```py
brain = BrainProcess("./test")
res = brain.send_start_cmd(20)
print(res)
```

So my questions are:

- What do these errors mean ?
- How do I fix them ?
- Did I use `asyncio.run()` correctly ?
- Is there a better way to encapsulate the process to send and retrieve data to/from it without making my whole application use `async` / `await` ?

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio.run` is meant to be used for running a body of async code, and producing a well-defined result. The most typical example is running the whole program:

```
async def main():
    # your application here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Of couurse, `asyncio.run` is not limited to that usage, it is perfectly possible to call it multiple times - but it will create a fresh event loop each time. This means you won't be able to share async-specific objects (such as futures or objects that refer to them) between invocations - which is precisely what you tried to do. If you want to completely hide the fact that you're using async, why use `asyncio.subprocess` in the first place, wouldn't the regular `subprocess` do just as well?

The simplest fix is to avoid `asyncio.run` and just stick to the same event loop. For example:

```
_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class BrainProcess:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        # starting the program in a subprocess
        self._process = _loop.run_until_complete(self.create_process(filepath))
        ...
...
```

> Is there a better way to encapsulate the process to send and retrieve data to/from it without making my whole application use async / await ?

The idea is precisely for the whole application to use async/await, otherwise you won't be able to take advantage of asyncio - e.g. you won't be able to parallelize your async code.

Comment: I haven't used async yet, but I'm curious about your example.  What is the difference with using `async def main():` and calling with `asyncio.run(main())` versus simply `def main():` and calling with `main()`

Comment: @RufusVS The difference is that the `async def` variant exposes individual methods like `_readline` and `send_start_cmd` as async, allowing them to be executed in parallel using `asyncio.gather` and other tools. Hiding them behind a sync facade using `asyncio.run` removes that possibility and makes them no different than ordinary sync methods for which `subprocess` would suffice.